# Two user authentication to use command

Tags: 16.04, command-line, security, two-factor-authentication

This might seem weird but I'm trying to find a way to have a double authentication requirement for the use of certain specific command on my server. For example, rebooting the machine would require the password of the current user AND the password of a second user or some sort of other code not directly available to the current user. This would be some sort of fail safe so someone those not run any critical command without at least one other person being aware of it. Does anyone know some sort of application I could use to do so? I know it could be MFA but that would still meen that a single user would be aware of the command not 2